# What encoding type is used on this string (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, encoding, escaping, url-encoding

I need to parse URLs from javascript source code using a different langauge(i.e. PHP and Java). The issue is that I don't know what kind of encoding is used on certain URLs(See below). Is there a standard(i.e. RFC, specifications) for this kind of encoding that I can use to implement it in the language I need? Initially I thought it simply backslashes the forward slashes but it seems is more than that as we have escaped characters such `\x3d...`

```
var _F_jsUrl = 'https:\/\/www.example.com\/accounts\/static\/_\/js\/k\x3dgaia.gaiafe_glif.en.nnMHsIffkD4.O\/m\x3dglifb,identifier,unknownerror\/am\x3dggIgAAAAAAEKBCEImA2CYiCxoQo\/rt\x3dj\/d\x3d1\/rs\x3dABkqax3Fc8CWFtgWOYXlvHJI_bE3oVSwgA';
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI

Comment: That looks like a standard JS string literal with some unnecessary escaping (`\/` instead of `/`, and `\x3d` hex escape instead of `=`).

Comment: @AlexMcMillan decodeURI/encodeURI doesn't produce anything close to that.

Comment: @Books try `decodeUri(_F_jsUrl)` and you'll see the expected URL.  I wasn't saying that was the answer to your question, just a hint :)

Comment: And to be clear, this has nothing to do with encoding.  Some code has simply escaped any non-ascii or non-uri-safe characters.

Comment: I think some JSON encoders escape `/` characters by default.